# PHP array push from JSON decode breaking array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$resultViewed='["88"]';

$viewed=json_decode($resultViewed);

if(!in_array("9",$viewed)){
    print_r($viewed);
    $viewed = array_push($viewed,"9");
    print_r($viewed);
}
```

This prints

```
Array ( [0] => 88 ) 2
```

Instead of

```
Array ( [0] => 88,[1]=>9 )
```

The array is valid, yet using `array_push()` to add another value isn't working as I'd expect.

Comment: I've go the answer you can stop negging me now thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove assignment: `$viewed =`:

```
$viewed = array_push($viewed,"9");
```

Just:

```
array_push($viewed,"9");
```

Its already in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), it returns the new number of items, **not** the values of the array.

Or just use the simple way:

```
$viewed[] = "9";
```